# How do you install Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 with minimal features?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

The reason I ask is I want a small installation size and I only use the product for writing code for school work. I will not need 3rd party software, web capability, or integration with other software and applications.

Comment: When you install visual studio 2017 you select the types of development you want to do.  You do not have to install web stuff if you are looking for windows forms

Comment: I know I only want the core features, but when I start the web installer it insists on immediately downloading and installing everything without giving me any prompts, choices, consent or warning.

Comment: No, it is not downloading "everything", it may seem so to you only. It needs an internet contact but not much data traffic to initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment now you requested for "command line to run the web installer in a certain predefined way say only download and install visual studio core editor and.net components". BTW, the recommendation **including** installing .NET components was a part of my *original* answer- now I splitted the answers, one for minimal install and this one for what you requested secondly, including .NET Visual Studio components:

The command line to install core and .net minimal is:

```
vs_xxxx.exe --layout %CD%\vs2017offline --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop
```

(set your individual downloaded .exe name for 'vs_xxxx.exe', my downloaded name was for example 'vs_enterprise__873301792.1489161815.exe')

Answer (score 1):

The new installer for Visual Studio gives you a lot of flexibility about which components to install.  By default, you'll have no additional features selected.  VS will only install what it calls the `Visual Studio core editor`, which is described as:

> The Visual Studio core shell experience including syntax-aware code editing, source code control and work item management.

With this, you'll get support for TextMate language grammars ([you can install any you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages)), but you won't have the overhead of installing any language services or project types.  So far, VS is a glorified editor; this minimal install will take 600MB.  If you're looking for something smaller, you should probably consider [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) instead.

### Workloads

The first tab of the new VS installer is the Workloads section.  This gives you some pre-packaged feature groups targeted at specific development platforms.  There are separate categories of workloads (Windows, Web, Gaming, and Other) and taking the Windows category for example, there are 3 different workloads available: UWP, .NET Desktop (like WinForms and WPF), and C++ Desktop development.

Each workload has required and optional features.  Some of the optional features will be selected by default as they are "recommended".  You can slim down by unselecting these.

If the workloads are too heavy-handed for you, you can use...

### Individual components

On this tab, you can piece together any single components you want.  If a workload seems too large, you can see what components it would install, then go to this tab and pick the smaller set you would like.

Note that some components do have dependencies (sometimes numerous), and the installer will show you all of the dependent packages added.  If you try to remove them, it will notify you of dependent components that will also be removed.

Comment: Can I use the command line to run the web installer in a certain predefined way say **only download and install visual studio core editor and.net components**. If so can someone list the proper structure for the commands for editing the execution of the web installer in the command line interface? (I already know how to run programs and installation files in the interface, I'm just hoping the visual studio web installer has it's own set of sub commands that I can utilize in the command prompt.)

Comment: @GulpDragondawn check out https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAnOfflineInstallerForVS2017.aspx

Comment: @GulpDragondawn I am not sure:  Do you have a problem currently? You downvoted my answer and such... Why do you want to work with the command line? Just selecting nothing when using web installer directly will install only core. If that seem not to work for you you will not be happier with the command line. Maybe there is still a misunderstanding? I can say that because I experimented with the commandline features for several days. Nevertheless I have listed the command line for .NET workload in a new answer.

Comment: **Phil**, I didn't realize I down voted it. I did like your answer. I work with the command line because I want to stay handy with using the command line for my games made to play on a recreated, in game command line interface. In summery, I just want to keep the knowledge of using the command line as fresh as possible for many aspects of my life. It isn't a deal at all for most people I understand, but for me, I really enjoyed the old command line only interface video games and will be making games like that myself as a stepping stone to becoming an Indie Game Designer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following alternatives:

1.
Minimal Visual Studio: Start the standard Visual Studio web installer, and select nothing, then you get the minimal installation for only the development environment (IDE), especially editor.

2.
If this is too big for you, you can use something similar to Visual Studio, for example, you can [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) editor or you can use [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net) as an alternative to Visual Studio. Open Source and smaller footprint.

You can work with every editor on the commandline using "csc.exe myhomework.cs" (CSharp compiler).

3.

**The solution with smallest footprint (without Visual Studio):**
Just use the editor you are used to, even notepad is possible: Depending on your .NET version and Windows directory, the compiler can be found for example here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

or

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
```

The 64 bit versions of those you get in the mirrored folders "Framework64" instead of "Framework"..

Normally you would like to download the whole .NET SDK (developer pack) additionally, but for a single homework, csc.exe might be enough.

Here is the developer pack for .NET 6.2 framework (Visual Studio uses that as kind of a kernel too).
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321